# Using a session to get an auto increment id from a query and using the id for another query

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a register page that I initially had one query going to a db table called 'users'. In the 'users' table I have a column called 'id' that is a primary auto increment field.

I then created a new query under my original that will send to a db table called 'payment status'. Everything in this query is working other than my attempt to use the 'id' created by the 'users' table and to put that into my 'payment_status' db table for the column 'user_id'. It always enters a 0 value in it.

```
if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

        $salt = Hash::salt(32);

        try {
            $user->create(array(
                'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
                'lastname' => Input::get('lastname'),
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'phone_number' => Input::get('phone_number'),
                'username' => Input::get('username'),
                'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                'salt' => $salt,
                'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'group' => 1
            ));
            $success = "You have successfully created an account. We will notify you once the account has been approved. Then you will be able to login.";
            echo $success;

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            $error;
        }
    }
```

The second query...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
$user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
$firstname = Input::get('firstname');
$payment_name = "Owes";
$payment_id = 1;
$payment_amount = 0;

//Query to add user's name to owes db table

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
/* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO payment_status (id, user_id, firstname, payment_name, payment_id, payment_amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    if ( false===$stmt ) {
  // Check Errors for prepare
  die(' Owes DB prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
$stmt->bind_param('iissii', $id, $user_id, $firstname, $payment_name, $payment_id, $payment_amount);
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      // Check errors for binding parameters
      die('Owes DB bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
$stmt->execute();

    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }   
  }
```

I'm attempting to get the 'id' from the 'users' table like this...

```
$user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
```

So I am trying to get the 'id' from the 'users' table and use that for the 'user_id' in the 'payment_status' table.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First you're not initializing (in the code you show) the `SESSION_ID` of the new user. You inserted successfully the user into the table `users` but you didn't start a session for him.

Secondly, if you want to get the id of the last user you might want to use [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: I start a session at the start of the file. I'm working with a php framework.

Comment: Starting the session doesn't make it assume values automatically. You need to specify content inside the session. For example, `$_SESSION['id'] = $last_user_id;`

Comment: Would `$last_user_id` replace my variable `$user_id` ?

Comment: No. After your code `echo $success` you need to set up the $_SESSION like I told you, and you need to retrieve the `user_id` from database.